# What docker image use for ionic CD / e2e testing? Ubuntu or just node?

Tags: docker, ionic-framework, e2e-testing, continuous-delivery, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to enable continuous delivery for one ionic project. 
I am going to use [Bitbucket pipelines](https://bitbucket.org/product/features/pipelines) which use Docker images.

I confused which Docker image I should use for the container.

Is it enough a node image or do I need a ubuntu image?
I might have to create my own image but what should be the base of that image.

Before running the end to end testing I will have to run few commands. e.g:

- pull from git master branch
- npm install
- npm install -g cordova ionic
- bower install
- run a gulp task
- run protractor test

The ionic project is also publish as a *webapp*, I deploy it to production from an Ubuntu 16.04 server (but served with ngnix) which make me think it is a good idea to have same environment in *dev* and *prod*.

With all of this, what should it be my Docker base image?

- [node:boron](https://hub.docker.com/_/node/)
- [ubuntu:16.04](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/)

In case both are valid options wouldn't be node image faster to build than ubuntu?